# How to detect face on different angles using opencv+python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect the face on different angles . Now my code detect faces , if the face is exactly in front of camera. But i want to detect faces on different angles . How could i do this .. Please help me.

My code is below:
**detector.py**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
rec.load("recognizer/trainningData.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,2,1,0,2)
while(True):
        ret,img=cam.read();
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3,5);
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
              cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255),2)
              id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
              if(id==1):
                  id="Aftab Ahmed"
              elif (id==2):
                      id="Ahmed"
              cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img),str(id),(x,y+h),font,255);
        cv2.imshow("Face", img);
        if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
            break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

In  order to detect the **non-frontal** portion of the face, you have to use a different classifier. For frontal face detection you have used **haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml** file. The side portion of the face is usually called the profile.

To detect the non frontal portion there is a different  `xml` file available namely **lbpcascade_profileface.xml**. You can find this `.xml` file on [THIS GITHUB PAGE](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/lbpcascades)

Use the `xml` to detect the profile.

Comment: Thanks @Jeru Luke for your suggestion. I will change the classifier.Can you suggest me any way to detect the images in darkness from live web camera and on distance (approx: 10 meter to 100 meter).

Comment: 100 m? SERIOUSLY!!!! 10m is a big deal, anything more than 10 m is really difficult

Comment: Ohhh. My project is working fine on 10 m. But client wants more than 10m, atleast between 30-50 and also i have problem to detect in darkness. Can you give me any hint to for darkness detection.

Comment: To improve the brightness however, you can use **gamma correction**

Comment: improve the brightness during capturing video/images ??

Comment: I have tried the haarcascade_profileface.xml and also lbpcascade_profileface.xml classifier BUT there is no face detection by using these calssifiers.Camera does not detect any object when i use these two classifiers.. Any suggestions..

Comment: This problem could not solved through Haar Cascades classifier. Now i have used optical flow method to detect objects (faces) continuously on any angle.

Comment: while thanks @Jeru Luke for your cooperation and feedback

Comment: @JeruLuke any haarcascade.xml for side face detection (left or right) ???